# Injector error using Angulartics with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics, angulartics

I have problem with adding **Angulartics**.

In my **app.js** I just added that two dependencies (**Angulartics** and the last one) you can see:

```
var smsApp = angular.module('smsApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'smsControllers',
  'smsFilters',
  'google-maps',
  'pascalprecht.translate',
  'angulartics',
  'angulartics.google.analytics',
]);
```

and then in my **index.html** I added: `<script src="./js/angulartics.js">
<script src="./js/angulartics-ga.js"> ---- paths to these files are ok`

but when I want to create that module with:

```
var injector = angular.injector(['smsApp', 'ng']);
```

I got this error:

`Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr]` [http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$injector/unpr?p0=%24rootElementProvider%20%3C-%20%24rootElement%20%3C-%20%24location](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/%24injector/unpr?p0=%24rootElementProvider%20%3C-%20%24rootElement%20%3C-%20%24location)

Without **Angulartics** it goes well! Please help me :) thanks

I'm following this [tutorial](http://luisfarzati.github.io/angulartics/).

Comment: maybe you should raise an issue at the angulartics github page

Comment: I haven't tried Angulartics, but I've had good luck with Angularytics, which likely does the same thing.
[Angularytics](https://github.com/mgonto/angularytics)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're reading the docs here: https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics

You need to install the angularitics.google.analytics plugin by running 'bower install angulartics-google-analytics --save'

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using injector?

If you're using `injector`, you're not using the regular AngularJS bootstrapping code, so `$rootElement` is not defined.

You could mock the object:

```
<script src="/path/to/angular-mock.js">
...
var injector = angular.injector(['smsApp', 'ngMock', 'ng']);
```

Or define it in your app explicitely

```
smsApp.config(['$provide', function($provide) {
    // Should match the element that contains your ng-app="smsApp" attribute
    $provide.value('$rootElement', angular.element(document.body)); 
}]);
```